# How to specify dependency in a JAR library

Tags: java, gradle

I am creating a JAR library and publishing it to nexus using Gradle for other projects to use. How can I specify that my JAR has a dependency on another library (Commons Lang 3)?

Comment: That's what the pom is for. You would need to publish it along with your jar

Comment: The jar contains compiled `.class` files for the classloader. If there are any unresolved dependencies, the classloader cannot do anything but whine at you. Resolving dependencies is what the build tool is for. Therefore, the dependency information goes into the pom, not into the jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you follow the guide on [building a Java library with Gradle](https://guides.gradle.org/building-java-libraries/?_ga=2.223852447.581458956.1519804894-603520137.1517337508). It contains the information you are looking for.

In short, your build file needs something like:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
}
```

And the publication to a maven repository will take care of adding that information to the Maven pom file that will be used by consumers of your library.